# Sphider MySQL Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sphider

I'm trying to install Sphider to search my site and when I try to create the MySQL tables I am getting this error:

```
create table query_log (
    query varchar(255),
    time timestamp(14),
    elapsed float(2),
    results int,
    key query_key(query)
    ) ENGINE = MYISAM;

MySQL said: Documentation
\#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(14),
    elapsed float(2),
    results int,
    key query_key(query)
    ) ENGINE = MYI' at line 3
```

How do I get round this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Sphider forums, it looks like this is an issue with the TimeStamp field type, or at least the way it's used in this CREATE TABLE query. (http://www.sphider.eu/forum/read.php?2,8933). On that forum page it is suggested that you:

1) editing the admin/install.php file, 
2) Changing line 139, 
FROM: 
time timestamp(14), 
TO 
time timestamp,

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as a timestamp(14).

The code should just be:

```
time timestamp;
```

Remove the (14)

Where the heck did you get that from, that they wouldn't understand basic mysql syntax?

Comment: Yeah, i guess it's a known problem for them, based on JNevill's post, but funny that they wouldn't have updated the source at this point rather than continuing to distribute something that's completely incorrect.

Comment: Agreed, my knowledge of php is good but I'm rusty in mysql so I couldn't do anything. Kinda bad

Comment: haha, well yeah, I use lots of tools in languages I don't know too well if at all myself.